# Trouble validating dynamically generated link

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, w3c-validation

The problem is with validating the following link:

```
    <link href="/WebResource.axd?d=iU6d9QgZtDnsqOJdmY0qJqVXyEU9Bc_DZHppuTGlpxU8YzwGet7OFPf9pflYz5SdwzuL1HVwxtSRZApovmcmRFW9P0ToSD3GFaTiOAqfOKHTYh7U0&t=634254225425826735" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and this is where w3c finds the error:

```
…UkrzqUngMzMpJmeFoz3FRJkFt3xFwsVmYNYc0&t=634254231258016859" type="text/css" re…

…krzqUngMzMpJmeFoz3FRJkFt3xFwsVmYNYc0&t=634254231258016859" type="text/css" rel…
```

in the first one its says that the  " t " is the problem and in the second one it says its the " = ".

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape & using `&amp;`.

Comment: I know that, but the problem is that i don`t have control over the link. I didn't add the link myself, its auto generated by asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the link, or is ASP.NET adding it to the page for you?

I believe the W3C validator's real problem is that it wants you to encode the ampersand (`& = &amp;`).

Comment: I didn't add the link myself, its auto generated by asp.net

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to modify this then.  Unless the component that generates the link is updated to use W3C compliant output...